Android 14 installed PWA deletes part of local storage on reverse proxied site
I have a web app/pwa that sits out on the cloud. It serves as a front-end and allows selection of a few internal sites that are reverse proxied upon selection. Both the front-end and the internal sites store a few things in local storage.
When running the site in Chrome browser on Android everything works great. I can see all keys in local storage from both the internal and external site. I can kill Chrome and the local storage is persisted properly upon restart.
If I "install" the pwa (not just add a shortcut) a new behavior emerges. When I kill the installed pwa, any local storage keys that were on the front-end are deleted. Oddly, the local storage keys that are on the internal site persist. Everything works as expected on IOS when using "Add to Home Screen".
I am guessing it's some sort of origin issue but the proxy is transparent and I don't see how Android could know the difference between the internal and external contexts.
I am running Android 14. I believe this is new behavior as it has worked fine in the past. Has anyone experienced this when installing a pwa on Android 14?
